# Is a production function bilinear?

Tags: production-function

I believe the following is the multiplicative property of bilinearity:

$$ Y=F(K,AL) $$
$$ c_1 F(K,AL) = F(c_1 K, AL) $$
$$ c_2 F(K,AL) = F(K, c_2 AL) $$

But when we have multiplied through the production function with a constant we have done so through each term as below

$$ c_3 F(K,AL) = F(c_3 K, c_3 AL) $$

e.g.

$$ \frac{1}{AL} F(K,AL) = F\left( \frac{K}{AL} , \frac{AL}{AL} \right) = F(k,1) = f(k) $$

What is the name of this property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such a function is called [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) of degree 1.

Answer (score 4):

**Constant returns of scale**

As observed above, in mathematical terms the function is homogeneous of degree 1. But in terms of economic theory, this is called a production function with constant returns of scale.

It means that if you change the inputs in a determinate proportion, the output varies in the same proportion.